# Inner workings of Google's Quick Draw

Tags: neural-network

I'm asking this here because I didn't find anything online.

I would be interested in how Google Quick Draw works, specifically:

1) How does it output the answer - does it have a giant output vector with a probability for each type of drawing?

2) How does it read the data - I see they've implemented some sort of order aware input system, but does that mean that they input positions of the interpolated lines that users draw? This is problematic because it's variable length - how did they solve it?

3) And, finally, which training algorithm are they using? The data grows each time someone draws something new, or do they just feed it into the algorithm when it's created?

If you know any papers on this or by miracle you work at Google and/or can explain how it works, I would be really greatful. :)

Comment: Seems like you're looking for specifics on the **Sketch-RNN** architecture. You can refer to [this Magenta article](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/sketch-rnn-demo) - it contains a thorough, complete and intuitive explanation. As a plus it also references other official publications such as [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.03477), which will likely give you all the info you want.

Comment: Thanks Julio Cezar Silva! people on Stack Overflow are so helpful :) not only they answer your questions but also format your post and correct your broken Engrish :P I really appreciate it, thanks a lot.